# Apache 2 + PHP 5: how to redirect an user to another domain

Tags: php, apache2, http-redirect

I have to `redirect` a site from another site.

I am using `PHP5` with `Apache 2` on a Debian Server.

Example:

If an user go to: `shop.oldsite.com`, should be redirected to `http://52.10.32.45:8081/shop/`.

I've tried with `htaccess` file and `redirect 301`, but i see the new address and I wish to hide the new address and keep `shop.oldsite.com` without broking SEO links (the spiders should go to `shop.oldsite.com` and redirect to new site).

Is it possible?

EDIT1: Thank you, for your answers. I'll look if Aruba (an Italian Hosting) supports mod_proxy and i'll let you know.

Comment: Are you sure that you need redirect and not **reverse proxy**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use mod_redirect with 'P' for proxy and have to enable mod_proxy

Comment: it worked in my dev environment, but not on Aruba. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to add header location in your index.php file to the location you mentioned

```
<?php
header("Location: http://52.10.32.45:8081/shop/");
?>
```

I hope this might help